# Meet and join symbols for mathematical lattice? (UTF: ∨ and ∧)

Tags: symbols

I'd like to use symbols for meet and join of two elements of a lattice, but I don't like \wedge and \vee because they're too big.

I'd like to use symbols the size of the ones on the wikipedia page in certain sections, e.g. [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Distributivity):

> S ∨ T or S ∧ T

Do these symbols have LaTeX commands? (Detexify didn't work for me.)

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf is a huge list of symbols

Comment: Note that symbols file Christian Hupfer points contains three different versions of `\wedge` and of `\vee`, two of each are smaller than the standard symbols.

Comment: Thanks to both, I was aware of the link but hadn't tried searching for different versions of wedge and vee. It looks like they are still called "wedge" and "vee", it just depends on what font you are using. I am trying to install mnsymbol now to see how it looks....

Comment: Another alternative to `\wedge` and `\vee` are the logical symbols `\lor` and `\land`.

Comment: the logical symbols are defined as the same wedge and vee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed the symbols used by `mathabx` and `MnSymbol` are smaller than the default ones.

But I suggest you not to load them, otherwise a lot of symbols will be changed by them.

You can for example, extract the definitions from the `mathabx` package and use them in your document.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

% Symbols \wedge and \vee from mathabx
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\wedge}         {2}{matha}{"5E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vee}           {2}{matha}{"5F}

\begin{document}

\[
S \wedge T \quad S \vee T
\]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Otherwise, you can define your own commands, let's say `\smallwedge` and `\smallvee`.

```
\newcommand{\smallwedge}{\mathrel{\text{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\wedge$}}}}}
\newcommand{\smallvee}{\mathrel{\text{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\vee$}}}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

\newcommand{\smallwedge}{\mathrel{\text{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\wedge$}}}}}
\newcommand{\smallvee}{\mathrel{\text{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\vee$}}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
S \wedge T \quad S \vee T
\]

\[
S \smallwedge T \quad S \smallvee T
\]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would like the wedge and vee from these packages more if they "floated" rather than resting on the same line as the text. Do you know if I can make that happen manually?

Comment: @usul See the edit, which, in my opinion, is much better than using symbols from `mathabx`

Comment: I really like the solution in the edit (making a small raised box). Thanks again.

Comment: is there a way to redefine \wedge and \vee without affecting \land and \lor? i'd like to use smaller symbols but due to "external needs" am stuck with the names.

Comment: also: why are the mathabx symbols rasterized for me, but not in the symbols-a4 document?